# Is it possible to fire event on jquery tabs plugin when the tab loads?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I want to fire an event when the tab loads, I already tried something like this:

```
$("#tabInicio").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.newTab.length != 0 && ui.newPanel.length != 0) {
            alert("XXXXX");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load) states that there is a `load` event especially for when a tab loads :

```
$("#tabInicio").tabs({
  load: function( event, ui ) {

  }
});
```

The `activate` event is triggered after a tab has been activated, and you should make sure you're testing the length of the right properties ?